# How to share a variable between the web users in Web2Py without a database

Tags: python, web2py

I have a Web2Py webapp which is a web interface for a blastn script. Now I need to limit the process running simultaneously, my thought is,

When the webapp starts, the way I did is, in default.py:

```
available_worker = multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 1

def get_workers():
    global available_worker
    return available_worker

def consume_worker():
    global available_worker
    available_worker = available_worker - 1

def free_worker():
    global available_worker
    available_worker = available_worker + 1

def index():
    if get_workers() > 0:
        consume_worker()
        # run a script
        free_worker()
    print get_workers()
```

Obviously, it will not work as every time the web loads, it resets the available_worker to `multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 1`.

I am just wondering, if there is a way I can share the availabe_worker across the web sessions or users.

So by the time a user A loads the page, the `available_worker` is 2, he runs the script. While user A is running the script, a user B loads the webapp, and he gets `available_worker` is 1, and he runs the script. While A and B are running the script, the a user C comes, he gets `available_worker` is 0, so he has to wait until either A or B finishes the script before he can run the script.

I am new to programming, a detailed explanation and sample code will be much much appreciated.

Thank you.

**Edit:**

I just realized my actual question is, when start a web2py app, how to init a variable, which will be only inited when the first time web2py starts. Then the sessions / uses can update the variable value. I found the problem of my code is, every time the page is loaded, it will reset the value to multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 1, even if I store the data to the database, it will be the same result.

Comment: Since handling persistent data is the whole point of a database, why don't you want to use one?

Comment: My boss doesn't want a database at all, and I just realized my actual question is, when start a web2py app, how to init a variable, which will be only inited when the first time web2py starts. Then the sessions / uses can update the variable value. I found the problem of my code is, every time the page is loaded, it will reset the value to `multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 1`, even if I store the data to the database, it will be the same result.

Answer (score 0):

A database *would* solve the problem, if used properly: every function would read the value from the DB and update the value there.  If the value in the DB hadn't been initialized, initialize it as you do in your current code.

If you can't use a DB, perhaps an external text file would do.

As for implementation: Wherever in your current code you access the value of `available_worker`, get it from the external resource; wherever you change it, update that external resource.

To (re-)initialize this resource whenever the server starts, you'd have to go outside of any individual app; you could modify `gluon.widget.py`, for example, since it is responsible for actually starting the server.

Note that, because any function in a web2py controller that does not have any parameters can be accessed as a web page, your `worker` functions can as well, even though they don't look like you want them to be able to.

Comment: Thank you. My problem is I don't know where to put the code that, read the `multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 1`, and write it to file system only when the app starts for the first time. And it will then read from the file to get the variable than write to file for next use. Can you please help?

Comment: I have tried that by adding the code to the top of the default.py. However, every time a new user visit the site (or simply refresh the page), it resets the count to `multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 1`, even if there are 3 jobs running.

Comment: I think I didn't explain correctly. I can do this by writing to a file for the first time, and if the file exists i just read the value from the file instead of from `multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 1`. However, if the server restarts, the record will still exist in either db / file system. But at that time, the available worker should be `multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 1`, but in the file it could be 0, then the script will never run. So I need to add the code to somewhere in web2py that only runs when the sever first starts. Am I able to do that?

Comment: Thank you for your updates. Can I add code to myapp/__init__.py, to check if available_workers.txt exists. If so delete it? Will it work? And is that a good practice?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps have a look at the [Python Multiprocessing library](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html).

Comment: Multiprocessing is not an option for my application for some reasons.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to share some data globally across users, you can use the web2py [cache](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#cache) feature. If you are running web2py in a single process, you can simply use `cache.ram` (you could also put the variable at the top level of a module and import it). Otherwise, use `cache.disk` or [`cache.redis`](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/13/deployment-recipes#Caching-with-Redis). As others have suggested, you can also simply use the database.

As an alternative, you might instead consider handling this with web2py's built-in [scheduler](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#web2py-Scheduler). You can launch as many scheduler workers as you see fit, and that will limit the number of simultaneous tasks that can be running.